# Get relative phase between matrix elemets

Tags: measurement

I have a N qubits system and I would appreciate a lot some suggestions on how I can get the relative phase between $$ \langle 0 \mid U^\dagger Z_n U \mid 0 \rangle$$ and $$ \langle 0 \mid U^\dagger Z_m U \mid 0 \rangle$$ where $Z_j$ is the Z-gate acting on the $j$th qubit and $U$ is a unitary (multi-gate) operator.
In general the $\mid 0\rangle$ state is not an eigenstate of $U^\dagger Z_n U$, hence $$ U^\dagger Z_n U \mid 0 \rangle= \sum_{j=0}^{2^N-1} \alpha_{j} \mid j \rangle$$

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers that you are calculating are real numbers. So, there is not an arbitrary phase between them that you don't know. To see this, set $|\psi\rangle=U|0\rangle$ and $Z_n=P^+-P^-$ where $P^{\pm}$ are projectors (and hence positive semi-definite). Then
$$
\langle 0|U^\dagger Z_nU|0\rangle=\langle\psi |P_+|\psi\rangle-\langle\psi |P_-|\psi\rangle
$$
Both terms are positive and hence the outcome is real. True, there is still the question about whether the value is positive or negative, but this isn't hard to uncover.

The way to determine the value $\langle 0|U^\dagger Z_nU|0\rangle$ is simply to prepare $|\psi\rangle$ and measure qubit $n$ in the $Z$ basis. It will give you the answer 0 with probability $p_0=\langle\psi |P_+|\psi\rangle$. Hence,
$$
\langle 0|U^\dagger Z_nU|0\rangle=2p_0-1.
$$
There is no unknown phase here; you get the sign directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, also the explaination was very clear!